# Show that there is exactly one binary operation making the set $\{e, x, y\}$ a group with $e$ the identity element

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $S=\{e, x, y\}$ be a set of three elements. Show that there is exactly one binary operation making the set $S$ a group such that $e$ is the identity element.

So I have produced the multiplication table as follows:

$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
\: & e & x & y \\ 
\hline
e & e & x & y \\ 
x & x & y & e \\ 
y & y & e & x
\end{array}$

I can see how to explain the first row and column, and also why $xy=e$ and $yx=e$, but I cannot justify $xx=y$ or $yy=x$, other than "*because elements cannot be repeated accross rows or columns*", which doesn't seem enough to me.

Comment: You said you can justify $xy=e=yx$, so consider what that tells you about $xx$ and $yy$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying that elements cannot be repeated across rows and columns is perfectly valid as long as you explain *why* they cannot be repeated.

To see why assume that they are repeated.  Then you'd have an equation of the form $ab = ac$ or $ab = cb$, which would imply $b = c$ or $a = c$, which cannot happen as you are assuming that $e, x, y$ are distinct.